# RTL grid in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, grid

Is there a way to grid in Tkinter From right to left (RTL)?

Like the picture:

[image]

Comment: If you are using `.grid(...)` then it shouldn't be a problem. If you are using `.pack()`, just use `side="right"` for all of your widgets.

Comment: I use `.grid` but it is LTR: 0 1 2 3 ...

Comment: Change the `column` parameters from 0, 1, 2, 3, ... to 3, 2, 1, 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't change tkinter's internal numbering of columns, but you can certainly arrange a layout from right to left by computing appropriate column numbers.

If you're creating a horizontal row of widgets such as buttons or labels, `pack` makes it easy to organize things from right-to-left by setting `side` to `'right'`.